# Supabase PGRST102 - Error All object keys must match

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, supabase

Can you help me?

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve or why it is happening.

I am consuming an api from nodejs to obtain certain data and as I am obtaining it, I am storing it in Supabase to obtain it, until I form my information object as I need it.

The problem is that when I want to update a table in supabase it throws me the error "All object keys must match", doing some research I found a forum that mentioned that maybe it was because the primary identifier was null, but I made sure by checking data by data . Then according to the PostgreeSQL error code "PGRST102" it is because the body that was sent in the request is not valid.

So my question is why can't I save my array object to my table? What am I doing wrong?

```js
export const summaryActivity = async(req: Request & any, res: Response) => {
    let supabase = instanceSupabase();

    try {

      // get the ID of the organization (important parameter to query data)
      const {
        data: organization,
        error: organizationError
      } = await supabase.from('organization').select('id');
      const organizationID = organization ? .map(id => id ? .id).toString();

      if (!organizationID) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'ID de la organización indefinido'
        });
      }

      // query between range date
      const date_start = req.query.date_start ? moment.utc(req.query.date_start).startOf('day').toDate().toISOString() : moment().toDate().toISOString();
      const date_end = req.query.date_end ? moment.utc(req.query.date_end).endOf('day').toDate().toISOString() : moment().toDate().toISOString();

      if (!date_start || !date_end) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Date Inválid'
        });
      }

      // consulted in API the hours worked of the day

      const activitiesDailyURL = process.env.API_BASE_URL + `v2/organizations/${organizationID}/activities/daily?page_limit=300&date[start]=${date_start}&date[stop]=${date_end}`;
      const activitiesDailyrequest = await req.app.authClient!.requestResource(activitiesDailyURL, req.app.session);

      // convert response to json
      const bodyActivitiesDaily = activitiesDailyrequest ? .body;
      const convertactivitiesDaily = JSON.parse(bodyActivitiesDaily.toString());
      const activitiesDaily: DailyActivityData = convertactivitiesDaily;

      if (!activitiesDaily) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Something wrong'
        });
      }


      // consulting the Projects table and obtaining the relationship projects x clients
      const {
        data: projectClients,
        error: projectError
      } = await supabase.from('projects').select('project_id, name, status,  clients ( client_id, name, status )');

      if (projectError) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Relacion Entidad Proyecto Inválido',
          projectError
        });
      }

      // filtering two objects to perform the union of them
      const joinProject = activitiesDaily.daily_activities.map(item => {
        const obj1Item = projectClients ? .filter(element => item.project_id === element ? .project_id);
        return obj1Item ? { ...item,
          ...obj1Item
        } : { ...item
        }
      });

      if (!joinProject) {
        res.json("Wrong to join project")
      }

      // consulting the users table (bring only the DEV, SAC, DESIGN roles)
      const {
        data: user,
        error: userError
      } = await supabase.from('user').select('user_id, username, status, daily_hours, rol').in('rol', ['DEV', 'SAC', 'DESIGN']);

      if (userError) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Relation Entity User Invalid!',
          userError
        });
      }

      // filtering user data response with joinProjects to perform the union of them
      const joinUser = joinProject ? .map(item => {
        const obj1Item = user ? .find(element => item.user_id === element ? .user_id);
        return obj1Item ? { ...item,
          ...obj1Item
        } : { ...item
        }
      });

      if (!joinUser) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Relation Entity Project Invalid',
          userError
        });
      }

      // iterating over the joinUser object to filter data for the same user

      let summedTracked = joinUser.reduce((acc, c) => {
        let filtered = acc.filter((el: DailyActivityJoin) => el ? .user_id === c ? .user_id);
        if (filtered.length > 0) {
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].tracked += +c.tracked;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].overall += +c.overall;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].keyboard += +c.keyboard;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].input_tracked += +c.input_tracked;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].mouse += +c.mouse;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].billable += +c.billable;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].manual += +c.manual;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].idle += +c.idle;
          acc[acc.indexOf(filtered[0])].resumed += +c.resumed;
        } else {
          acc.push(c);
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);

      // types of summedTracked
      const convertObject: DailyActivityJoin[] = summedTracked;
      const newArr: any[] = [];

      // map convertObject to create a new array where new items will be passed with the corresponding calculations

      convertObject.map(element => {

        let range = {
          min: 10000,
          max: 99999
        }
        let delta = range.max - range.min

        const rand = Math.round(range.min + Math.random() * delta);

        const overall = element.overall;
        const tracked = element.tracked;
        const dayliHours = element.daily_hours
        const calculatedActivity = (overall / tracked) * 100;
        const totalHoursTracked = (tracked / 3600);
        const percentHours = (totalHoursTracked / dayliHours) * 100;

        newArr.push({
          activityid: rand,
          id: element.id,
          date: element.date,
          user_id: element.user_id,
          project_id: element.project_id,
          task_id: element.task_id,
          keyboard: element.keyboard,
          mouse: element.mouse,
          overall: element.overall,
          tracked: element.tracked,
          input_tracked: element.input_tracked,
          manual: element.manual,
          idle: element.idle,
          resumed: element.resumed,
          billable: element.billable,
          created_at: element.created_at,
          updated_at: element.updated_at,
          username: element.username,
          status: element.status,
          daily_hours: element.daily_hours,
          rol: element.rol,
          "0": element[0],
          percentActivity: Math.round(calculatedActivity),
          hoursTracked: totalHoursTracked.toFixed(2),
          percentHours: Math.round(percentHours),
          createRegister: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')
        });
      });

      if (!newArr) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Seguimiento de la actividad del usuario indefinido',
          userError
        });
      }

      console.log(newArr);

      // Find the activity-historic-tracked table within an array of unique ids if they already exist within it

      const findId = newArr.map(id => id ? .id);
      const {
        data: record,
        error: errorHistoric
      } = await supabase.from('activity-historic-tracked').select('*').in('id', findId)

      if (errorHistoric) {
        res.json({
          error: true,
          message: 'Something wrong!',
          errorHistoric
        })
      }


      // If it doesn't exist
      if (record ? .length !== 0) {

        // doSomething...


      } else {

        // Otherwise update the activity-historic-tracked table

        const {
          data: historicoActividad,
          error: recordError
        } = await supabase.from('activity-historic-tracked').upsert(newArr);

        if (recordError) {
          return res.status(403).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Error in upsert',
            recordError
          });
        }

        res.status(201).json(historicoActividad);


      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
          title: 'API Error',
          message: 'Internal Server Error'
        });
      }
    }
```

I also leave you the structure of my table in Supabase

```
Table

identity primary key historic_id
numerical identification
activity ID int8
date text
user_id int8
project_id int8
task_id int8
int8 keyboard
int8 mouse
traced int8
input_tracked int8
manual int8
idle int8
resume int8
billable int8
text created_in
updated text_in
username text
status text
daily_hours int8
rol text
percentActivity float8
hoursTracked float8
percentHours float8
createregister date
"0" json
```

Comment: Hi Izlia, can you create an [mcve] where we can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Can you provide pointers as to which part of your code fails and produce a minimal example of this as @Mansueli asked above. Also what is this part of your table structrure? `"0" json`, you have a column called "0" of json type?